# What is the pkg analog of "apt show"?

Tags: freebsd, pkg

`pkg info` displays full information on the *installed* packages. How do I get the same output for packages not yet installed? On Ubuntu, `apt show` does exactly that.

**ETA**: An example of what I'm looking for, taken from Ubuntu.

```
$ apt show sudoku
Package: sudoku
Version: 1.0.5-2build2
Priority: optional
Section: universe/games
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Peter Spiess-Knafl <dev@spiessknafl.at>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 124 kB
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libncurses5 (>= 6), libtinfo5 (>= 6)
Homepage: https://github.com/cinemast/sudoku
Download-Size: 41.9 kB
APT-Sources: http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
Description: console based sudoku
 This sudoku puzzle generator/solver features:
  * character based (curses) interface;
  * cross-platform (Minix, Unix, Windows) with full source code (ANSI C);
  * generates hints upon request;
  * classification of board difficulty (very easy, easy, medium, hard or
    fiendish);
  * generation of new boards;
  * easy entry of boards published in newspapers, Internet, ...;
  * multiple output formats (text, csv, HTML, PostScript).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pkg rquery [query statements] [package name]` to replicate `apt show`. [This forum post](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/apt-cache-show-alternative-in-pkg.50902/) is outlining its similarity to `apt-cache show`. The `rquery` [manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg-rquery&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD+10.1-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html&sektion=8) covers the basics of query commands. An example would be something along the lines of this:

```
pkg rquery %n:\n%o:\n%p:\n%e pkg
```

This shows the name of the package (%n), the origin of the package (%o), the prefix of the package (%p), and the description of the package (%e). All of which split on to their own newline (\n). There are many options and formats. Please check with the [manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg-rquery&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD+10.1-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html&sektion=8) for more specific queries. To get an identical output to `apt show` you will need to nearly use every option but if you only need to know one or two things you can just query for those.

Answer (score 0):

For a short equivalent try:

```
$ pkg search -gfSn ba*le
bastille
Name           : bastille
Version        : 0.9.20220216
Origin         : sysutils/bastille
Architecture   : FreeBSD:13:*
Prefix         : /usr/local
Repository     : FreeBSD [pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/FreeBSD:13:aarch64/quarterly]
Categories     : sysutils
Licenses       : BSD3CLAUSE
Maintainer     : christer.edwards@gmail.com
WWW            : https://bastillebsd.org
Comment        : Jail automation framework
Annotations    :
Flat size      : 247KiB
Pkg size       : 37.4KiB
Description    :
Bastille helps you quickly create and manage FreeBSD Jails.

The project focuses on secure defaults, automation and
repeatable templates.

WWW: https://bastillebsd.org
```

`-g` glob pattern for entire search field
`-f` full information
`-Sn` search on name